# Full Text Search on mLab with mongoose: MongoError: text index required for $text query

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mlab

I'm trying to perform a full text search on a database on mLab. However, apparently the text indexes are not being created.
Mongoose version is 5.4.16

Schema:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var mySchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  }
});

mySchema.index({
  title: "text",
  description: "text",
});

mongoose.model("Model", mySchema);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Model");
```

Use following to perform the search:

````
Model.find({
    $text: { $search: query }
  }).exec(function(err, codes) {...}```
````

I get the following error:

MongoError: text index required for $text query

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why but I had the same problem with Mongoose and Mlab.

Manually I did the following to solve it.

1) Connect to mlab using the mongo shell

```
mongo ds245387.mlab.com:45387/<dbname> -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>
```

2) Run `db.products.createIndex( { title: "text", "description": "text" } )`

3) `db.products.getIndexes()` should return something like:

```
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "_fts" : "text",
        "_ftsx" : 1
    },
    "name" : "title_text_description_text",
    "ns" : "database-name.products",
    "weights" : {
        "description" : 1,
        "title" : 1
    },
    "default_language" : "english",
    "language_override" : "language",
    "textIndexVersion" : 3
}
```

Note: products is your collection name

4) Try your query again!

MongoDB text-search [reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/)